# Dump float to specific precision in YAML file with Python

Tags: python, ruamel.yaml

How can I specify a precision to which floating point numbers should be dumped in a YAML file, using `ruamel.yaml`?

For example, this:

```py
import sys

import numpy as np
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
my_arr = np.random.random((1, 3))
yaml.dump(my_arr.tolist(), sys.stdout)
```

might output:

```
- - 0.16197964351016936
  - 0.6259092493078636
  - 0.4335685294945195
```

How can I choose how many decimal places to include in such YAML output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a specific float format with ruamel.yaml, and don't know how to achieve it, then
first check if it round-trips and that ruamel.yaml can preserve the format:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- - 0.16197
  - 0.6259
  - 0.433
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
- - 0.16197
  - 0.6259
  - 0.433
```

As you can see ruamel.yaml preserves the individual lengths of each scalar float.

Then you can inspect the `data` using `print(type(data[0][0]))`, which will tell you
that those sequence elements are loaded into a list of `ScalarFloat` instances. Those
instances can be instantiated with among other things a width and a precision

```
import sys
import random
import ruamel.yaml

data = [[]]
for x in range(3):
    data[0].append(ruamel.yaml.scalarfloat.ScalarFloat(random.random(), width=7-x, prec=1))
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

and that gives:

```
- - 0.59012
  - 0.7968
  - 0.079
```

Comment: If necessary you can get scientific notation (`1.2e-9`) as well with some extra parameters and set an anchor on the value. A more complete invocation is `ScalarFloat(value, 
width=width,
prec=prec,
m_sign=m_sign,
m_lead0=lead0,
exp=exp,
e_width=e_width,
e_sign=e_sign,
anchor=node.anchor)` (from `constructor.py`) please note that all but the first are keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks, but negative numbers seem to become positive. E.g. `import sys, ruamel.yaml; data = [ruamel.yaml.scalarfloat.ScalarFloat(-0.18472, width=10, prec=1)]; ruamel.yaml.YAML().dump(data, sys.stdout)` seems to output the same as if the number was positive. What am I doing wrong? I am using version 17.4.

Comment: AFAICT Numpy's `random.random` cannot generate negative numbers. In case you have any from somewhere else, you'll have to provide the `m_sign` (mantissa sign) parameter, which can be `False` (i.e. N/A), `"+"` or `"-"`), Make sure to check the code in `constructor.py` if you have infinitiy or NaN values